# How to create different edge style for specific cells in JGraphX?

Tags: java, jgraphx

In my graph I'm using "**EntityRelation**" edge style. In **entity Relation Edge Style**
the edges comes out from left and right side of the mxcell only. Couldn't create top down edge using this edge style. I have set default edge style as "**entity Relation Edge Style**". But for some mxcells i need to draw edge from top to bottom (or) bottom to top.Can i set specific edge style for particular cells?.
And simply i need an edge style as like in "Xcos(scilab)".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [JGraphX User Manual](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/manual_javavis.html#2.2.3.1).
One of the `mxGraph.createEdge()` methods accepts a `String` as style configuration. Or you can use the `mxCell.setStyle()` method to change the style post creation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method for setting alternate edge style in jGraphX

**alternateEdgeStyle**

mxGraph.prototype.alternateEdgeStyle
Specifies the alternate edge style to be used if the main control point on an edge is being doubleclicked.  Default is null.